# qt 5 how to prevent repaint whole window if i want repaint only 1 widget

Tags: c++, qt

Minimal code example:

```
class Boo : public QPushButton{
public:
    Boo(QWidget* w) : QPushButton(w){}
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ev){
        qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<this->objectName();
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ev){
        qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__;
    }

private:
    QTimer t;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Boo *b1, *b2;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    b1 = new Boo(this);
    b1->setObjectName("O1");
    b2 = new Boo(this);
    b2->setObjectName("O2");
    connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this](){
         b2->repaint();
     });
    t.start();
    t.setInterval(10);
}
```

Outputs infinitely: MainWindow::paintEvent Boo::paintEvent "O1" Boo::paintEvent "O2"

but i call repaint only for button b2.  Using "QWidget::repaint(int x, int y, int w, int h)" or :QWidget::update()" also invoke repaint for main window.

Problem exists on Qt5.12/5.15 and windows11, but looks like general qt bug.

This issue cause high GPU consumption in our more complex GUI application.

Ok. I found the reason myself, after add:

```
...
b1->setGeometry(15,15, 12, 12);
...
b2->setGeometry(35,35, 14, 14);
...
 virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ev){
        qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<ev->rect();
    }
```

ouput says, that actual repaint is done only for button region:

MainWindow::paintEvent QRect(35,35 14x14)
Boo::paintEvent "O2" QRect(0,0 14x14)

Important thing: ivoke setGeometry for button, not just add as child. In other case (usable only for toy example, ofcourse) repaint button with unset geometry will lead to repaint every button with unset geometry.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue when adding the widgets to a layout (and not setting geometry)? I didn't run your code, but as I read it, in the original, the buttons should overlap, thus repainting 1 button would cause a repaint for the region where both are displayed. That would explain the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Qt repaints by default all parents too, to allow widgets being partially transparent. If Qt doesn't repaint the parent on an update, some pixels of the previous `paintEvent` may still be visible.

Qt provides two methods to optimise this behaviour when no transparent background is needed:

- Set [`autoFillBackground`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop). This option is preferred in case of an opaque background color.
- Set [`Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) to indicate that you will paint the whole widget (with opaque colors).

**More information**

- Qt documentation: [QWidget: Transparency and Double Buffering](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering)

Comment: None of these methods helped. PaintEvent is called anyway. The most significant issue, that this is the reason of high GPU consumption even in this simple application (up to 26% of GPU NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB).

Comment: @StackGit If you find the answer, please consider adding it as a separate answer (instead of adding it to your original question).